# How to set GRUB to auto boot into windows if there is no user input

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, grub, windows-update

I would like to know if there is a way to configure *GRUB* so that it will auto boot into *Windows* if there is no user input after a while.

This is to smooth out the process of Windows update. As many of us know, Windows updates will reboot many times during the update. and since GRUB is the default boot manager, it will not boot into Windows unless we manually choose Windows.

In the case of a windows update, we will have to sit through the whole thing and choose Windows every time the computer restarts. Not to mention windows 10 auto updates (unless you turned it off in group policy or by setting the wifi to a metered connection), so we might wake up one day, choose Windows on the grub screen, just to find out a few seconds later that we will have to sit and wait a couple of hours at the computer choosing Windows every time it restarts.

I haven't dual booted the ubuntu 16.04 distribution of linux in fear of the above happening. If there is a way to configure GRUB to auto boot into windows if there is no user input after a while, since I need to make sure that every thing fits together nicely before dual booting ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way to change the boot order in `grub` config.

You have to be `root` or a user with `sudo` permission.

First of all backup the old config with

```
cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.bak
```

then edit `/etc/default/grub` with your favourite editor (gedit, vim, nano,etc).

Find the line that says: **GRUB_DEFAULT=0**

Change the GRUB_DEFAULT Value to the number that you want to select by default (counted from zero), save the file an run.

```
update-grub
```

The new configuration is built. Reboot to test.

Comment: so, when the timer counts down to 0 and i haven't chosen an OS, GRUB will auto boot into the OS that has the value of 5 (if i edit GRUB_DEFAULT=5). But how will i know which number is Windows? Will it just which line Windows is on in the GRUB menu. If possible, is there a video link for this?

Comment: @MassiveFire It follows the order of the lines as they appear in the grub menu starting from 0.

Comment: @MassiveFire If you are afraid of doing a manual change on a text file you can use a graphic tool called **GRUB Customizer**, check [this](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/04/install-grub-customizer-ubuntu-16-04-lts/)